# How to implement a gridview with different size griditems?

Tags: android, gridview

How to implement a gridview with different size griditems? as we have in pintrest app...

ex :-

[image]

I tried with Staggeredgridview but it has lots of bugs in setting vertical - horizontal spacing, position replacement etc etc...

Any suggestions please...

Comment: What happens when you use the default gridview with two columns and custom sized items?

Comment: they are overlapping with eachother when the item length is more

Comment: You can't with the standard Gridview. The only one I've heard recommended is StaggeredGridView. If it's not working for you, you might have to roll your own.

Comment: @Geobits - Currently I am using StaggeredGridView only but I was unable to set horizontal & vertical spaces between items & numColumns = 'autofit' is also not working

Comment: You could include margins in your list items to control spacing. Autofit just isn't supported, though. You'll have to make an intelligent guess for "numColumns" based on screen width, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using Staggered library. Refer [this link](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo). Hope it helps.

Comment: Currently I am using StaggeredGridView only but I was unable to set horizontal & vertical spaces between items & numColumns = 'autofit' is also not working